# using Object Oriented for running tests

Tags: c#, selenium, oop

What's the best way to create positive and negative tests by object oriented paradigm?
Today, I have created two different tests and I have the feeling I can improve my code by using it wisely.

Negative test:

```
  [Test]
    public void LoginWithOutStudentBirthDate()
    {
        var LoginWithStudent = new Login(_webdriver).LoginPage(StudentID, "", ParentID);
    }
```

Positive test:

```
  [Test]
    public void LoginWithFullStudentDetails()
    {
        var LoginWithStudent = new Login(_webdriver).LoginPage(StudentID, BirthDate, ParentID);
    }
```

Login Method:

```
 public FamilyPage LoginPage(string StudentID,string StudentBirthDate,string ParentID)
    {
        _parentID.SendKeys(ParentID);
        _birthDate.SendKeys(StudentBirthDate);
        _studentID.SendKeys(StudentID);
        _buttonSubmit.Click();
        return new FamilyPage(_webdriver);
    }
```

Comment: I think your code looks perfect.

Comment: I guess you'll have to check the outcome after performing `_buttonSubmit.Click()`. Was there an error message? You'll have to define how an "incorrect login" looks like and throw an `Exception` once you identity such behavior.

Comment: Where does the `StudentID`, `BirthDate` and `ParentID` data come from? Personally I prefer having all input data inside the test method, or wrapped in some "scenario" class. Similarly for checking the result, even if there is an `Exception` that makes your test fail (which is what you want), I would prefer catching it explicitly and `Assert.Fail()` if there was not exception where it was expected.

Comment: " _buttonSubmit.Click();" this looks like a bad thing to do especially in unite tests. Are you trying to do unit testing or integration testing?

Comment: @FilipCordas I'm trying to do integration test. what do you suggest?
Thank you all for the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you code looks good, however I see following issue.

1. As you are returning `FamilyPage` from the LoginPage Method, it would be difficult to handle negative scenarios. This might work with `if-else` for Login Page however, for other page which has many flows would complicate your method.

My advice is as below.

1. Do not return the next page unless your website has a very strict flow.
2. In the constructor of `LoginPage` verify that you have landed on the right page and so for `FamilyPage`. This way you can create the FamilyPage object in test case to make sure Login Is successful.